# Update version of org.springframework.boot to 1.3.2

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I use org.springframework.boot version 1.2.5.Release and application runs without errors. Now I want change version of org.springframework.boot to 1.3.2.
My pom file is

```
    ...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>                   
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>           
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>            
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>           
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>                       
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>          
    </dependency>           

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>           
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>           
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>           
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.trecloux</groupId>
            <artifactId>yeoman-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <bowerInstallArgs>install --no-color</bowerInstallArgs>
                        <buildArgs>build --force --no-color</buildArgs>
                        <!--<skipTests>true</skipTests>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>%regex[.*Test.*]</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           

    </plugins>
</build>...
```

And application runs without errors.
But when I change version of org.springframework.boot to 1.3.2

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
...
```

I get error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.system.ApplicationPidListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:407) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you clean the target directory ( `mvn clean`)?

Comment: Yes. I call `mvn clean`, then `mvn install`. Error appears on `mvn install` command when it try run tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Boot api docs indicate [ApplicationPidListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/system/ApplicationPidListener.html) was deprecated in favor of [ApplicationPidFileWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/system/ApplicationPidFileWriter.html) in 1.2.0 and apparently removed in Spring Boot 1.3.x.  Are you using this class?  You only showed us your POM, not your spring configuration.

There is nothing wrong with your POM.  Do not make the suggested edits from Praveen.  Track down where you are using ApplicationPidListener and change it to use ApplicationPidFileWriter.

Comment: Thanks! I used `ApplicationPidListener` in `spring.factories` file. The change it to `ApplicationPidFileWriter` helped